# Creating zoom-pan video from a picture in Linux

Tags: linux, video-editing

I would like to make a six second video using six images. Each second is sliding over one image from its top to its botom. Or some other motion effect – I would like to try several.

I tried

- kdenlive
- Imagination
- Videoporama
- PhotoFilmStrip

The first one has not enough settings (don't remember what exactly) and all those have rather poor quality – the resized picture is very "aliased" (like no quadratic filter was applied during resizing).